# How to remove this gap between two sections (one on top of the other)?

Tags: html, css

I have two sections(a header section and main body section) and for whatever reason there is this big gap. I have tried many things such as setting padding to 0, margin to 0, etc but nothing seems to get the job done. Please help!
http://jsfiddle.net/Pfc2Z/2/

Here's the relevant HTML

```
    <section class="header">
        <section class="logo">
            <img src="logo.png" height="100px" width="200px" alt="Img Not Available">
        </section>
        <section class="link">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>    
                        <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section class="main">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </section>
```

Here is the CSS

```
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:#46a7bb;
}
.header {
    background-color:#313145;
}
.logo {
    padding-left:20%;
}
.logo, .link {
    display:inline-block; 
}
nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.main {
    background-color:white;
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your main section contains a paragraph tag. Paragraph tags have their own default styling (read margins and paddings). If you remove that, you'll be just fine. Just add the following to your CSS classes:

```
p {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

See this here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9deH/1/

**UPDATE:**

Yes its possible. You can do that by making use of `class selectors` or `id selectors`. `Class selectors` will let you use this kind of styling again whenever you want to use it (re-usability) while not altering the default paragraph styling.

`ID selectors` on the other hand, will apply only an only to this paragraph.

See the `class` selector example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9deH/2/

See the `id` selector example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9deH/3/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I like this idea, but this changes the margin and padding of all the paragraphs. If later on I want the margin and padding to go back to normal for a few paragraph tags, is it possible?

Comment: @Icarus I have edited my answer based on your comment!!

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what i was looking for. I thought the .someclass was a programming language thing only; I had no clue we could do this in css.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the layout and they doesn't have any margin or padding problem. The problem is with the paragraph `<p>Hello World</p>`. It has a default margin. You can fix this problem by **removing its default margin to 0 or sending it down with padding** but its not a good idea to override the default paragraph style ***use padding to the parent instead***. Here's the link, i used (20px padding to the main section). Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/fyfWq/

Comment: I haven't developed a website in a few years now so I don't really remember everything. Can you please explain "use padding to the parent"? Thanks you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Satwik's answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes he is right. I also said that. It's the default margin problem. But you shouldn't just remove it that way. It was a suggestion along with the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes here looking for an annoying gap they cannot explain, and they've gone through all the usual checks on margin, padding, and borders:

If you have made your elements `inline-block`, then the browser will render white space between your elements at whatever font-size is defined there.  I chose to solve this by adding a negative margin, but you can also solve it by removing white-space in your html (either by commenting it out, or... wait for it... using your delete / backspace button).

I came here looking for this answer to this problem, so hope it helps someone else out there.

Update: Just re-looking at the question above, I see an inline-block there, so perhaps this was actually the issue!